# Wrong Output using Mutex and Pthread Library

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

The purpose of the below program is to learn Mutex and Pthread library. The main() creates three thread. (thread 1, 2 & 3). 
Each thread one-by-one sequentially, reads one character per file (different file) and stores into the global constant. 
Example thread 1 reads character 'a' from file1, then wait for thread 2 & 3 to the same (i.e. read 'b' and 'c' from file2 and file3 respective). 

Once the reading is finished, we want the main to print the global constant to file.out

I have attempted to program the same but getting incorrect output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char glob_var, strtemp[1024];
pthread_mutex_t lock;
int cnt = 0;
char inp[3][10] = {"file-1.in", "file-2.in", "file-3.in"};

void * thread_func(void * arg);

void * thread_func(void * arg)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char * argu = (char *)arg;
    fp = fopen(argu, "r");
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        glob_var = fgetc(fp);
        if(feof(fp))
        { 
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            break ;
        }
        if (glob_var != '\n')
            strtemp[cnt++] = glob_var;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return (void *)0;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fpout;
    pthread_t threads[3];
    int i = 0;

    fpout = fopen("file.out", "w");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_func, (void *)inp[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    strtemp[cnt] = '\0';
    cnt = 0;

    while(1) {
        glob_var = strtemp[cnt++];
        fprintf(fpout, "%c\n", glob_var);
        if (strtemp[cnt] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fpout);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Input File

File1 File2 File3
a     u     t
o     .     #
e     p     a
i     r     m
e     n     $
```

---

```
Output File

From Above Code         Desired Output
t                       a
#                       u
r                       t
a                       o
m                       .
!                       #
$                       e
s                       p
m                       a
u                       i
.                       r
p                       m
r                       e
n                       n
```

Comment: Your mutex isn't initialized correctly.

Comment: @EOF while this is true, a mutex could never achieve what OP wants here, anyways...

Comment: when opening a file, for instance with 'fopen()', always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: `pthread_mutex_t lock;` should be: `pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`

Comment: this line: `if(feof(fp))` has the problem of feof() not true until after trying to ready past the end of the input file.  That is one iteration too late.  Suggest: replace that line and the prior line with: `if(EOF ==  (glob_var = fgetc(fp))) { `

Comment: the function: `fgetc()` returns an 'int', not a 'char', so the variable: `glob_var` needs to be defined as: `int glob_var;`

Comment: suggest, for sequencing, to have the main function 1) pass in a sequence number  then in the thread function: 2) perform a `cnt%3` and compare to the passed in sequence number to determine if it is 'this' threads' turn to read a character.  3) call `nanosleep()` at the end of each execution of the thread to give the other threads a chance to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mutex` here only makes sure no more than one thread accesses your global variables at the same time. It doesn't give you any guarantees on the order in which the threads are scheduled. For what you want to do, a `mutex` is the wrong synchronization primitive because it is designed for exactly that: exclude other threads from accessing the same resource at the same time.

You want to explicitly allow a specific thread *after* another thread. This *can* be done using `semaphores`. You would need one per thread. So, declare a second `sem_t` array globally with 3 entries, initialize the first to 1, the others to 0. Then, pass just a *thread number* (0 - 2) to your threads and do something like:

```
int next = num + 1;
if (next > 2) next = 0;
sem_wait(sems[num]);
/* your code, accessing inp[num] */
sem_post(sems[next]);
```